# Mysql query: pull data from two tables, nested query?

Tags: mysql, join

Given two tables:

orders table

| order_id | name | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Joe | 34.99 |
| 002 | Bob | 97.21 |
| 003 | Bill | 100.32 |

order_products table

| order_product_id | order_id | product_id | name | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | 358 | green dog toy | 1 | 9.99 |
| 002 | 001 | 736 | purple cat toy | 1 | 7.34 |
| 003 | 001 | 921 | blue dog toy | 1 | 5.43 |
| 004 | 001 | 925 | red cat toy | 1 | 4.48 |
| 005 | 002 | 921 | blue dog toy | 1 | 5.43 |
| 006 | 003 | 801 | yellow dog toy | 1 | 9.43 |

How do I select all orders and then get all products for that order (orders.order_id=order_products.order_id)?  There can be more than one product per order so I don't think I can left join it.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Show desired output for shown source data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to just use this simple query:?

> SELECT orders.name,order_products.name FROM order_products,orders
> where orders.order_id=order_products.order_id;

which returns:

```
joe,"green dog toy"    
joe,"purple cat toy"    
joe,"blue dog toy"    
joe,"red cat toy"    
Bob,"blue dog toy"    
Bill,"yellow dog toy"
```

This query return all orders that have at least one product.
Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But I'd like to have one row for Joe, one row for Bob, and one row for Bill.